# Is it possible to use a different datastore for each subdomain with Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Lets say I have the domain:

```
mywonderfulapp.com
```

I would like to have a subdomain per client. For example:

```
clientA.mywonderfulapp.com
```

I would like client A to go to the URL `clientA.mywonderfulapp.com` and retrieve its data privately and client B could to go to `clientB.mywonderfulapp.com` to retrieve its own data.

Application code should be the same but they should use a different datastore.

Is this possible with Google App Engine Java?

Thanks in advance!

Thanks for the feedback received. It seems that an Google App Engine Aplication can't use several datastores per subdomain.

### Solutions

@jldupont and @Steve Jessop: 
Let me try to capture what you meant. Please, correct me if I did not understand you.

Every entity has field called prefix which stores a subdomain string where it belongs. This string can be captured for example with a filter configured in web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SubdomainFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filters.SubdomainFilter</filter-class>        
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SubdomainFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then use a query such as:

```
select from guestbook.Greeting where subdomain == 'clientA'
```

**Questions**

- Would not be slow to perform queries in such a huge "database"?
- Does it not have security implications to have every user and account data mixed in the same datastore?

Comment: I'm not sure your definition of "different datastore" exists. As I understand it, there is only one datastore: every entity (of any kind, belonging to any user) in Google datastore lies in a single BigTable. You could add a field to all your kinds, saying what subdomain they belong to, and include an equality check on that in your queries. Grab the subdomain from the request headers (and validate it against the current user, probably).

Comment: 'Would not be slow to perform queries in such a huge "database"'. Nope. This is exactly what BigTable is designed to do well. When you specify the subdomain, it will jump straight to the (part of the) index where the entities with that subdomain are stored all together, and start reading. "Does it not have security implications" - maybe, in that if you specify the wrong subdomain on your query then you'll leak data. But it's no worse than using Google accounts and looking up the data by userid, which is what every other App Engine app in existence does.

Comment: Oh, and in case I wasn't clear, when I said every entity belonging to any user, I meant any user of Google App Engine. That is, your entities for your app, and my entities for my app, are in the same BigTable, presumably with some "hidden fields" which datastore uses to ensure that only my app sees my entities, and only your app sees yours. If Google is happy with the performance, then so am I :-)

Comment: Really appreciated your comments Steve. Help me a lot

Answer (score 4):

this is generally called [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). fortunately, since this question was originally asked, the app engine team added a feature called [namespaces](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/overview.html) that supports multitenancy and lets you partition your datastore the way you want.

you'd create a namespace for each client, set the namespace based on the subdomain in your code, and then all datastore, memcache, task queue, and other API operations would be restricted to that namespace.

to answer your follow up questions, using namespaces won't impact performance, and assuming you always set the right namespace, they're as secure as using an entirely separate app id.

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement. But I'm not sure on how to create sub-domain, so that ClientA's users can access app through 'clientA.mywonderfulapp.com'. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, **no** this is not possible.

Why wouldn't a `prefix` based on the subdomain not be enough?

Comment: a prefix based on the subdomain would definitely work. however, now that namespaces are available (see below), you'll want to use them instead. they're easier, more robust, wouldn't require extra custom indexes for some queries, and are supported across different APIs.